# User with slow data rate, slows down all other users on the server

Tags: c++, sockets

I am developing an echo server that accepts multiple clients using the poll technique. The source code is [here](https://github.com/YiannisBourkelis/poll-echo-client-server).

The problem I am facing is that when a client sends data to the server with a slow rate, it will slow down all other clients, waiting for the slow user to finish sending all the data first.

To overcome this problem I though about creating worker threads on the server and send each socket read there, but this would make things more complicated because I will have to use some kind of synchronisation so that not two threads will read from the same socket descriptor at the same time.

What method are you using to overcome this problem with the slow clients? Is there any design pattern for this?

Edit 1: Some code to describe the question better
Edit 2: Added a check for POLLIN before recv

```
//simplified code
//poll loop
do {
    rc = poll(fds, nfds, -1);

    //when some socket descriptors are ready for read, read them all
    for (i = 0; i < nfds; i++)
    {
        if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
            //here if the fds[i] socket descriptor has a slow data rate, it will slow down all the other
            //clients waiting for the server to complete the recv with the slow client.
            int bytes_recv = recv(fds[i], buffer, 1024, 0);
        }
    }

} while (end_server == false);
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are required to post your code here within your quesiton [mcve]. In addition, your question is far too broad and asks for opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Rob It is a question about software architecture and I am asking for a solution on a very specific problem I described. An experienced developer on sockets programming will understand without code. Of course I can post some code if needed, but I have already included a link to the source code because it is around 500 lines.

Comment: You are **required** to post your code **here within your question**. A **minimal but complete** example that shows the problem. You ask NO specific question but broad "What are you using?" and "Are there any patterns?" If you cannot post a minimal amount of code here, then you need to delete this and ask your question elsewhere. Stack Overflow is not the platform for this.

Comment: @Rob The question is about a design architecture on this specific problem. I posted some code to illustrate the problem better and I hope it helps.

Comment: *"when some socket descriptors are ready for read, read them all"* Why, exactly? Read only those socket descriptors that are ready for read.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, this is what I was meaning. All those that are ready for read

Comment: But your code does in fact read all sockets, not just those that are ready. So of course you block on those that don't have anything to read, defeating the whole point of `poll`. Also, your code can't possibly compile - `poll` wants `pollfd*`, `recv` wants `int`, `fds` can't be both at the same time.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is a simplified version of the complete code that exists here: https://github.com/YiannisBourkelis/poll-echo-client-server/blob/master/src/poll-echo-ssl-server/poll_server.cpp . Yes, I will check for the revents to be POLLIN and then I will call recv. I will edit the code above